# Как правильно обрабатывать данный случай из матрицы условным ветвлением?

Tags: python, матрицы

Памятка: прошу не писать короткий код ясный Вам, я новичок, и хочу чтобы в таком виде, в каком я описал код и идею, прошу объяснить в данном контексте.

Таска: нужно брать матрицу и вводить значения до тех пор, пока не будет введено слово end, дальше код должен суммировать значение соседей слева, справа, сверху, снизу, и вставлять сумму на позицию откуда считалось, и выводить матрицу такого же размера.

Вот код:

```
matrix = [[int(x) for x in input().split()]]
inside_matrix = input()
final_matrix = []
while inside_matrix != 'end':
    '''
    Данная часть описывает ввод до тех пор, пока не будет вписано слово: end.
    '''
    matrix.append([int(i) for i in inside_matrix.split()])
    inside_matrix = input()
if len(matrix) < 2:
    '''
    Для одного элемента матрицы
    '''
    print((matrix[0][0]) * 4)
else:
    '''
    Для всех остальных случаев
    '''
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        temporary_list = []
        for j in range(0, len(matrix)):
            inside_temporary_list = []
            if (i == 0) and (j == 0):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == 0) and (j == -1):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif i == 0:
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif j == 0:
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif j == -1:
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif (i == -1) and (j == 0):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif i == -1:
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == -1) and (j == -1):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            else:
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            temporary_list.append(*inside_temporary_list)
        final_matrix.append(temporary_list)
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    print(*final_matrix[i])
```

Проблема заключается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я не могу правильно достучаться до последнего элемента, а так как у нас идет итерация, то значения i и j не могут иметь те, значения которые я им указал во ветвлениях, и я не знаю как правильно указать последний элемент массива в данном куске кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Грубо говоря я описал все варианты случаев, и чтобы они обрабатывались.

П.С. Я столкнулся с новой проблемой на произвольных данных:

```
matrix = [[int(x) for x in input().split()]]
inside_matrix = input()
while inside_matrix != 'end':
    #Данная часть описывает ввод до тех пор, пока не будет вписано слово: end.
    matrix.append([int(i) for i in inside_matrix.split()])
    inside_matrix = input()
if len(matrix) < 2:
    #Для одного элемента матрицы
    print((matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]))
else:
    #Для всех остальных случаев
    final_matrix = []
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        temporary_list = []
        for j in range(0, len(matrix)):
            inside_temporary_list = []
            if (i == 0) and (j == 0):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == 0) and (j == len(matrix) - 1):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif (i == 0) and (j != (0 or len(matrix) - 1)):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (j == 0) and (i != (0 or len(matrix) - 1)):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (j == len(matrix) - 1) and (i != (0 or len(matrix) - 1)):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif (i == len(matrix) - 1) and (j == 0):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == len(matrix) - 1) and (j != (0 or len(matrix) - 1)):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == len(matrix) - 1) and (j == len(matrix) - 1):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            else:
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            temporary_list.append(*inside_temporary_list)
        final_matrix.append(temporary_list)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print(*final_matrix[i])
```

Нужно для второго for указать range не по длине внешнего списка, а по длине внутреннего списка из двумерного массива.

Comment: у вас i `in range(0, len(matrix))`, почему вы сравниваете `if (i == -1)`? Это вы последний элемент так хотите проверить? Тогда, наверное, `if (i == len(matrix)-1)`

Comment: @splash58 нет, я забыл описать идею, ее опишу в самом посте, я хочу сравнить индексы массива, то есть на данной итерации индекс такой то такой то, нужно чтобы отрабатывал этот код.

Comment: так он же не может быть минус один, если он [0 - len(matrix))

Comment: @splash58 я знаю, я поэтому и задал вопрос, как мне сделать сравнение i\j если они будут последними индексами

Comment: `elif (i == -1) and (j == -1)` - не выполнится никогда, ибо выполнение уже свернёт на `elif j == -1`. То же и касательно `elif (i == -1) and (j == 0)` и `elif j == 0`

Comment: я это делаю, чтобы не было ошибка out of range, я поэтому и делаю жесткие ограничения, и вот задался вопросом, как переписать последний индекс.

Comment: @DaymaNkinG `if (i == len(matrix)-1)`

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, подал идею, надо попробовать)

Comment: @splash58 спасибо сплеш тебе за подсказку, и спасибо акине, мой код отрабатывает уже лучше, но нужно дорабатывать, спасибо вам огромное)

Comment: @Akina спасибо тебе)

Comment: @splash58 спасибо мой код работает, чуть позже выложу код в ответы)

Comment: @Akina спасибо мой код работает, чуть позже выложу код в ответы)

Comment: @splash58 есть идеи как записать длину не внешнего массива, а длину внутреннего массива из двумерного массива?

Comment: а адресуете вы его как?

Comment: @splash58 в том и дело я не знаю как достучаться до внутреннего массива, сам по себе двумерный массив - это matrix, но достучаться до какого либо внутреннего списка я могу путем matrix[][], а inside_matrix - э то лишь строка, куда я заношу значения ввода с клавы.

Comment: и что нужно, inside_matrix запихнуть в matrix?

Comment: @splash58 оно и так запихивается, но могу ли я по inside_matrix искать длину, разве len() не будет считывать с пробелами?

Comment: а вы как строку держите? какая-то странная идея - у вас стоблец строк получается?

Comment: @splash58 я нашел решение как считывать длину внутреннего массива в двумерном массиве - это len(matrix[0])

Comment: Это правильно, что вы со своим кодом боретесь, но так можно писать на любом языке, например на php. Надо пользоваться средствами, которые предоставляет питон. Когда разберетесь со своим, посмотрите, что я вам в ответе написал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слайсы границ не боятся, надо только следить, чтобы ниже нуля не оказался индекс.

Вот так можно посчитать сумму всех соседей

```
def getSum(i,j,M):
    ts = 0
    for row in M[max(0,i-1):i+2]:
        ts += sum(row[max(0,j-1):j+2])
    return ts - M[i][j]
```

теперь представьте что у вас есть двумерный, пусть даже с разными размерами внутренних списков, список matrix. Вот так строится новый список тех же размерностей, содержащий суммы соседей

```
s = []

for x in range(len(matrix)):
    temp = []
    for y in range(len(matrix[x])):
        temp.append(getSum(x,y,matrix))
    s.append(temp)
```

---

А можно, как любят спецы по пиону, совсем страшно - построить всю матрицу сумм в одной строке

```
s = [[sum(matrix[row][col] for row in range(max(0,i-1),min(len(matrix),i+2)) for col in range(max(0,j-1),min(len(matrix[row]),j+2))) - matrix[i][j] for j in range(len(matrix[i]))] for i in range(len(matrix))]
```

Comment: понял, тоже ознакомлюсь, но я закодил наконец и забагфиксил все, гляньте код)

Answer (score 1):

Вы совершенно зря рассматриваете подсчет суммы как новую задачу для каждого элемента. Она для каждого элемента одинаковая.

Рассмотрим функцию, которая считает сумму соседей для элемента:

```
def getSum(i,j,M):
    t=0
    #Определим число столбцов и строк
    wsize=len(M[0])
    hsize=len(M)
    #для каждого соседа элемента мы смотрим есть ли он
    if (i-1>=0):
        t=t+M[i-1][j]
    if (i+1<hsize):
        t=t+M[i+1][j]
    if (j-1>=0):
        t=t+M[i][j-1]
    if (j+1<wsize):
        t=t+M[i][j+1]
    return t
```

Определим число столбцов и строк исходной матрицы

```
wsize=len(matrix[0])
hsize=len(matrix)
```

Создадим новую такого же размера

```
newMatrix=[[0] * wsize for i in range(hsize)]
```

Далее заполним ее элементы с помощью функции `getSum`

```
for i in  range(hsize):
    for j in range(wsize):
        newMatrix[i][j]=getSum(i,j,matrix)

print(newMatrix)
```

Обратите внимание, что теперь для формирования матрицы по новым условиям (например соседей не 4, а 8) нужно лишь переписать функцию `getSum`

Comment: обязательно ознакомлюсь с вашим вариантом решения, но я также смог все таки добить свой код!)

Answer (score 0):

Я дописал код, и хочу принести благодарности, кто помогал и давал некоторые идеи и направления.

```
matrix = [[int(x) for x in input().split()]]
inside_matrix = input()
while inside_matrix != 'end':
    #Данная часть описывает ввод до тех пор, пока не будет вписано слово: end.
    matrix.append([int(i) for i in inside_matrix.split()])
    inside_matrix = input()
if (len(matrix) == 1) and (len(matrix[0]) == 1):
    #Для одного элемента матрицы
    print((matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]))
else:
    #Для всех остальных случаев
    final_matrix = []
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        temporary_list = []
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[0])):
            inside_temporary_list = []
            if (i == 0) and (j == 0):
                if len(matrix[0]) == 1:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
                elif len(matrix) == 1:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[(0)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
                else:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == 0) and (j == len(matrix[0]) - 1):
                if len(matrix) == 1:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(0)][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
                else:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif (i == 0) and (j != (0 or len(matrix[0]) - 1)):
                if len(matrix) == 1:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(0)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
                else:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (j == 0) and (i != (0 or len(matrix) - 1)):
                if len(matrix[0]) == 1:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
                else:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == len(matrix) - 1) and (j == 0):
                if len(matrix[0]) == 1:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]) + (matrix[(0)][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
                else:
                    inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (j == len(matrix[0]) - 1) and (i != (0 or len(matrix) - 1)):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif (i == len(matrix) - 1) and (j != (0 or len(matrix[0]) - 1)):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif (i == len(matrix) - 1) and (j == len(matrix[0]) - 1):
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            else:
                inside_temporary_list.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            temporary_list.append(*inside_temporary_list)
        final_matrix.append(temporary_list)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print(*final_matrix[i])
```

Comment: (matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]) + (matrix[0][0]) = 4*matrix[0][0] и зачем вам тут скобки. И вообще, зачем вы выделяете этот случай?

Comment: `(matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]) + (matrix[(i + 1)][j]) + (matrix[i][0])` - почему два раза  (matrix[i][0]) ?  `matrix[-1]` -  это совсем не `matrix[i-1]`. дальше не осилил

Comment: @splash58 да код работает, все ок, да мой код не идеален, но он подошел), а кусок с 4 * matrix[0][0] можно было бы переписать, но я чет протупил)

Comment: но вы понимаете, что matrix[-1] - всегда последний саб-лист? сделайте тестовую матрицу побольше

Comment: @splash58 в каком месте код не верный, у меня на любой матрице все работает

Comment: @splash58 я понял как можно переписать и обращаться к внутреннему списку не через len(matrix[0]), лучше через len(matrix[i]). То есть, то что вы описали чуть ниже в своем примере, я его усвою, переварю и буду в след. раз использовать.